# Error: variable not declared in GUI design file

Tags: c#, user-interface

Newbie question. I downloaded the source of a project written in C#. There is an error occurring in one of the designer files used for constructing the GUI. Source attached below:

```
namespace Neurotec.Samples
{
partial class MainForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.enrollFromFilePanel = new Neurotec.Samples.EnrollFromFile();
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel = new Neurotec.Samples.EnrollFromMicrophone();
        this.tabPageVerify = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.verifyVoicePanel = new Neurotec.Samples.VerifyVoice();
        this.tabPageIdentify = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.identifyVoicePanel = new Neurotec.Samples.IdentifyVoice();
        this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPageVerify.SuspendLayout();
        this.tabPageIdentify.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPageEnrollFromFile);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPageVerify);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPageIdentify);
        this.tabControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(551, 398);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TabControlSelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // enrollFromFilePanel
        // 
        this.enrollFromFilePanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.enrollFromFilePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.enrollFromFilePanel.Name = "enrollFromFilePanel";
        this.enrollFromFilePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(540, 316);
        this.enrollFromFilePanel.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPageEnrollFromFile
        // 
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Controls.Add(this.enrollFromFilePanel);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Name = "tabPageEnrollFromFile";
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(546, 322);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.Text = "Enroll From File";
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        // 
        // tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone
        // 
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Controls.Add(this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Name = "tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone";
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(546, 322);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.Text = "Enroll From Microphone";
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // enrollFromMicrophonePanel
        // 
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel.Name = "enrollFromMicrophonePanel";
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(540, 316);
        this.enrollFromMicrophonePanel.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPageVerify
        // 
        this.tabPageVerify.Controls.Add(this.verifyVoicePanel);
        this.tabPageVerify.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPageVerify.Name = "tabPageVerify";
        this.tabPageVerify.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(546, 322);
        this.tabPageVerify.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tabPageVerify.Text = "Verify Voice";
        this.tabPageVerify.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // verifyVoicePanel
        // 
        this.verifyVoicePanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        this.verifyVoicePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.verifyVoicePanel.Name = "verifyVoicePanel";
        this.verifyVoicePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(546, 322);
        this.verifyVoicePanel.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tabPageIdentify
        // 
        this.tabPageIdentify.Controls.Add(this.identifyVoicePanel);
        this.tabPageIdentify.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPageIdentify.Name = "tabPageIdentify";
        this.tabPageIdentify.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(543, 372);
        this.tabPageIdentify.TabIndex = 3;
        this.tabPageIdentify.Text = "Identify Voice";
        this.tabPageIdentify.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // identifyVoicePanel
        // 
        this.identifyVoicePanel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.identifyVoicePanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.identifyVoicePanel.Name = "identifyVoicePanel";
        this.identifyVoicePanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(543, 372);
        this.identifyVoicePanel.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(551, 398);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.Text = "Simple Voices Sample";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainFormLoad);
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.MainFormFormClosing);
        this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromFile.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPageVerify.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPageIdentify.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TabControl tabControl1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPageEnrollFromFile;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPageEnrollFromMicrophone;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPageVerify;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPageIdentify;
    private EnrollFromFile enrollFromFilePanel;
    private EnrollFromMicrophone enrollFromMicrophonePanel;
    private VerifyVoice verifyVoicePanel;
    private IdentifyVoice identifyVoicePanel;

}
```

}

The errors state that some variables were undeclared or unassigned. As an example, the variable "enrollFromFilePanel" is said to be undeclared but it was created with the line "private EnrollFromFile enrollFromFilePanel;". I am sorry that I cannot provide an sscce and I hope that the solution is something simple. Thank you.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact compiler errors.

Comment: The variable 'enrollFromFilePanel' is either undeclared or was never assigned. This is the compiler error.